# ECIES Encryption for python and iOS

Tags: python, ios, swift, encryption-asymmetric, ecies

I'm attempting to implement ECIES encryption in iOS Swift which has to be compatible with server python, but I'm encountering compatibility issues. I followed the instructions from an article for both Python and iOS, but when decrypting, it throws an error. Is there a library available that supports ECIES encryption compatible with both Python and Swift?

Repo macOS: https://github.com/agens-no/EllipticCurveKeyPair

--------For python-----------

and I have tried this repository:
https://gist.github.com/dschuetz/2ff54d738041fc888613f925a7708a06

https://gist.github.com/ateska/09e1c874494bba8e381ccd8d851b0df8

article: https://darthnull.org/secure-enclave-ecies/

Comment: Have you tried googling "ECIES Python" and "ECIES Swift"?  Libraries for both already exist.

Comment: Note that there are different ECIES standards (s. e.g. [here](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/asymmetric-key-ciphers/ecies-public-key-encryption)). Especially when working across platforms or with different libraries, the libraries involved must be chosen so that they implement the same standard.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to find the standard in iOS which compatible in python, it seems difficult.